# I can't get images to load in NextJS

Tags: image, webpack, next.js

[Here's a photo of my file structure. I'm new to NextJSS and still fiddling with it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsAn9.png) I have tried writing this two different ways to no avail.

next.config.js

```
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withImages = require('next-images');
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const optimizedImages = require('next-optimized-images');

const nextConfig = {
  webpack(config, options) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/,
      use: [{
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 100000
        }
      }]
    })
    return config
  }
}

module.exports = withPlugins([
  [withCSS],
  [withSass],
  [optimizedImages]
], nextConfig);
```

next.config.js

```
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withImages = require('next-images');
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const optimizedImages = require('next-optimized-images');

module.exports = withCSS(
  withSass(withImages({
    webpack (config, options) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 100000
          }
        }
      })
      return config
    }
  })))
```

I am importing my images as so:

```
import picOne from '../images/picOne.png';
import picTwo from '../images/picTwo.png';
```

I have also tried using them as such:

```
 <img src={require('../images/picOne.png')} alt="image" />
```

I have also tried alternating url-loader with file-loader to no avail.

Haven't found anything online yet that resolved this :(

Comment: read the doc https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving

Comment: @de3 Hey, thank you! I just did that and it didn't change anything though. All of the images were successfully packaged into .next and server but won't render when I run dev.

Comment: @de3 Never mind, that did fix it. I had to get rid of my old src={} syntax. Thanks!